# How to run Intel Graphics settings / Command Center manually?

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics

I have just installed the latest graphics driver from the Intel website today, selected the "Clean install" option. The downloaded installer is called "gfx_win_101.2115.exe", and it warns that the Command Center will be installed:

[image]

And yet, I cannot find it anywhere. Not in the desktop right-click menu, not in the Start menu search, or just scrolling the start menu. How can I run it manually, i. e. where the executable is supposed to be located and how to run it?

- The driver itself is clearly installed properly, it's 31.0.101.2115 DCH.
- I have installed the driver twice and rebooted a number of times for good measure.
- Windows 10 x64 21H1, Intel UHD 630 (Core i5-8500T).

Comment: [You need to install it from the Microsoft Store](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000055840/graphics.html)  You can install it [here](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/intel%C2%AE-graphics-command-center/9PLFNLNT3G5G?hl=en-us&gl=us&rtc=1)

Comment: @Ramhound Really? There's no other way? Ouch. Thanks. If you're certain it's the only way, please post an answer.

Comment: Intel removed it over 5 years ago to comply with Microsoft's requirements for display drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound: You should put up an answer.